# eclipse RCP - making the IFolder persist after the last View has been closed

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have created an IFolder with a placeholder for my views in RCP on eclipse Helios on XP with Java 1.6 like so;

```
    IFolderLayout mainFolder = layout.createFolder("mainfolder, 
            IPageLayout.LEFT, (float) 100.0, layout.getEditorArea());
    mainFolder.addPlaceholder("myview:*");
```

And this works as expected with a greyed out area, which is populated by the myview when it is created and with subsequent views. However if the last view is ever closed, the whole IFolder area disappears and future views are instantiated in the wrong area/folder of the workbench.

I see a few people mentioning this problem back in 06, but I can't find any solutions and I don't want to keep force resetting the perspective just when the last folder has gone.

http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg15873.html
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53312.html#91951958

I am thinking that I might have to hook the close view method to check to see if it is the last view and re-create the IFolder.

there seems to be a method to prevent the layout from closing;

```
layout.getViewLayout("myview").setCloseable (false);
layout.getViewLayout("myview:*").setCloseable (false);
```

but I can't seem to get that to effect the folder from collapsing...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Overwrite the method *isDurableFolder(...)* in your *WorkbenchWindowAdvisor* so that it looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean isDurableFolder(String perspectiveId, String folderId) {
        if( "my.perspective".equals(perspectiveId) && "my.mainfolder".equals(folderId) ) {
              return true; 
        }
        return super.isDurableFolder(perspectiveId, folderId);
    }
```

Replace *my.perspective* and *my.mainfolder* with the ID of your Perspective and Folder. This will create a durable *ViewStack* for your Folder.

FYI: By default the `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor#isDurableFolder(...)` returns `false`. This causes `PageLayout#createFolder(...)` to create the *ViewStack* as **not** durable. The Method `PageLayout#createPlaceholderFolder(...)` is not able to set the *ViewStack* durable!